# Match multiple elements in line with different element size in 2 csv files

Tags: python, csv

Hello I am trying to match 2 patterns from each line in 2 csv files that I have. the files are with different number of columns each. The files looks like:
file1.csv:

```
rrs,A907T,
rrs,A908G,
Rv0678,R134*,Amino_acid_change
tlyA,A67E,Amino_acid_change
tlyA,A806G,Amino_acid_change
tlyA,R14W,Amino_acid_change
tlyA,R18*,Amino_acid_change
```

File2.csv looks like:

```
SNP,CN,1918160,T221A,L74Q,tlyA
SNP,N,1472750,A908G,rrs
INS,I,1471827,i19AGA,inter,murA,rrs
SNP,N,1472138,C293T,rrs
SNP,N,1472425,T580C,rrs
SNP,N,1472549,G704A,rrs
SNP,N,1472135,C290T,rrs
SNP,I,1473637,A21G,inter,rrs,rrl
SNP,N,1472557,G712A,rrs
SNP,N,1472537,R14W,tlyA
SNP,CZ,1918745,A806G,*269W,tlyA
SNP,I,1473632,G26A,inter,rrs,rrl
```

Expected output:

```
In both lists we found: 
rrs,A908G
tlyA,A806G,Amino_acid_change
tlyA,R14W,Amino_acid_change

Uniq to File1 are:
rrs,A907T,
Rv0678,R134*,Amino_acid_change
tlyA,A67E,Amino_acid_change
tlyA,R18*,Amino_acid_change
Uniq to file 2 are:
...
```

The code I use (to no avail) is:

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
import re
import csv

with open("File1.csv") as f,open("file2.csv") as f2:
    result =[]
    result2 = []
    fileLines = f.readlines()
    for fileLine in fileLines:
        lineElems = fileLine.split(',')
        geneID = lineElems[0]
        cordRegx = lineElems[1]
        f2lines = f2.readlines()
        for Mahaline in f2lines:
            Mahaline = Mahaline.strip()
            MahalineElms = Mahaline.split(',')
            idM = MahalineElms[-1]
            cordM = MahalineElms[-2]
            if idM == geneID:
                if cordM == cordRegx:
                    print (idM, geneID, cordRegx)
```

Thanks for any help!!
Cheers

Comment: There are varying columns in the second file and the values that appear to match appear in different columns in different rows.  You'll need to explain the relationship between the files.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return [x.strip().split(',') for x in f.readlines()]

def print_list(inlist):
    return "\n".join([",".join(x) for x in inlist])

f1 = read_file('File1.csv')
f2 = read_file('file2.csv')

x_in_both = [x for y in f2 for x in f1 if all([z in y for z in x[0:2]])]
y_in_both = [y for y in f2 for x in f1 if all([z in y for z in x[0:2]])]
in_1_only = [x for x in f1 if x not in x_in_both]
in_2_only = [y for y in f2 if y not in y_in_both]



print(f"""In both lists we found:
{print_list(x_in_both)}

Uniq to File1 are:
{print_list(in_1_only)}

Uniq to file 2 are:
{print_list(in_2_only)}
""")
```

The result:

```
In both lists we found:
rrs,A908G,
tlyA,R14W,Amino_acid_change
tlyA,A806G,Amino_acid_change

Uniq to File1 are:
rrs,A907T,
Rv0678,R134*,Amino_acid_change
tlyA,A67E,Amino_acid_change
tlyA,R18*,Amino_acid_change

Uniq to file 2 are:
SNP,CN,1918160,T221A,L74Q,tlyA
INS,I,1471827,i19AGA,inter,murA,rrs
SNP,N,1472138,C293T,rrs
SNP,N,1472425,T580C,rrs
SNP,N,1472549,G704A,rrs
SNP,N,1472135,C290T,rrs
SNP,I,1473637,A21G,inter,rrs,rrl
SNP,N,1472557,G712A,rrs
SNP,I,1473632,G26A,inter,rrs,rrl
```

I cannot see why the counts are not matched correctly.  Add some print statements to check counts:

```
def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return [x.strip().split(',') for x in f.readlines()]

def print_list(inlist):
    return "\n".join([",".join(x) for x in inlist])

f1 = read_file('File1.csv')
print(f"Read {len(f1)} rows from File1, {len({''.join(x[0:2]) for x in f1})} unique keys.")
f2 = read_file('file2.csv')
print(f"Read {len(f2)} rows from file2, {len({','.join(y) for y in f2})} unique rows.")


x_in_both = [x for x in f1 for y in f2 if all([z in y for z in x[0:2]])]
print(f"Both Count for File1: {len(x_in_both)}")
y_in_both = [y for y in f2 for x in f1 if all([z in y for z in x[0:2]])]
print(f"Both Count for file2: {len(y_in_both)}")
in_1_only = [x for x in f1 if x not in x_in_both]
in_2_only = [y for y in f2 if y not in y_in_both]



print(f"""In both lists we found:
{print_list(x_in_both)}

Uniq to File1 are:
{print_list(in_1_only)}

Uniq to file 2 are:
{print_list(in_2_only)}
""")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike. This seems to work, however, when I count the rows in all files things don't add up..? In the real file 1 I have 1245 rows. In file2 992 rows. Matching in both 276. Uniq to file1 773, uniq to file2 793. If I sum uniq file1 and uniq file 2 + in both = 2022. If I sum the input rows of file1 and file2 they add up to 2237. 2237-2023= 214 instances missing. How can I sanity check why im missing rows?

Comment: @OrenTzfadia Add some print statements.  I added examples to my answer.